# Entity Framework Code First Table Hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

In our database we have tables called LookUps (generic, there is no table called lookups) -
1. MaritalStaus(LookUpId, description).
2. TypeOfRelations(LookUpid, description)
3. Title (LookUpid, description)

What would be best way to define the model for this kind of tables. I was thinking like, if I create a generic class like

```
public class LookUp<T>
{
//where T is one of lookup kind
}

public class MaritalStatus : LookUp
{
 // no field
}
```

// same for Title and relationship type.

But i am confuse how to put it all together
1. Do I have to match all the types with tables etc. for configuration?
2. Generic lookup has no table in the database?
Any good tutorial or suggestions welcome.
Thanks,
Daljit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing some concepts, I presume. I believe you intend to have access to your lookup tables using only one class in the following scheme:

```
var maritalStatus = new Lookup<MaritalStatus>();
var typeOfRelations = new Lookup<TypeOfRelations>();
```

And then leave EF to figure out how to deal with the reading and writing of data to and from the database using the generic `Lookup<T>` class. This kind of approach is not possible with EF because there can be no `DbSet<T>` of generic types, as EF would not know what tables to read and write from beforehand (T could be anything).

One way out of this is to use Table per Type inheritance on EF. If you can change the database schema then you can create a parent LookUp table and have the other LookUps all descend from the parent, then you can use EF's Table per Type feature and call the `.OfType<T>` extension method during your queries.

Check Morteza Manavi's article for a very good explanation on how to to just that:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx

If you can't change the database schema then you can use the Table per Concrete class approach that gets by without a concrete table for the parent class, also described on Morteza Manavi's article here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, it is really good answer and tutorial is very informative. Thanks a lot. Sometimes it is better to know what cannot be done.